# Configuring StreamingContext in Apache Zeppelin

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, apache-zeppelin

My goal is to read streaming data from a stream(in my case aws kinesis) and then query the data. The problem is that I want to query the last 5 minutes data on every batch interval. And what I found is that it is possible to keep the data in a stream for a certain period(using StreamingContext.remember(Duration duration) method). Zeppelin's spark interpreter creates the SparkSession automatically and I don't know how to configure the StreamingContext. Here's what I do:

```
val df = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kinesis")
  .option("streams", "test")
  .option("endpointUrl", "kinesis.us-west-2.amazonaws.com")
  .option("initialPositionInStream", "latest")
  .option("format", "csv")
  .schema(//schema definition)
  .load
```

So far so good. Then as far as I can see the streaming context is started when the write stream is set and started:

```
df.writeStream
  .format(//output source)
  .outputMode("complete")
  .start()
```

But having only the SparkSession I don't know how to achieve a query over last X minutes data. Any suggestions?